# Clash of Clans Connection

Tags: clash-of-clans

I connected my Clash of clans account with Google Play when I was at town hall 7. It somehow got disconnected from Google play (it shows a red button saying "Disconnected") and now I am at Town Hall 8. What will happen if I reinstall the game without connecting it again? will it start from town hall 7 or town Hall 8?

In simple words, do I need to connect it every time it gets disconnected to sync my progress or does it get synced and only one time a connection is needed?

Comment: You want to sync your data online without having an internet connection? How should that work? If you uninstall an app, it also deletes the app data. So if the app doesn't save a file somewhere else (you should see a "write storage" permission in the list), it can't keep the data when you uninstall it. It would probably also help to say which device you're playing on (Android/iOS, OS version, device model, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting an app on Android and iOS deletes all app data. If you were not connected to Google Play or Game Center, your data was not synced to the cloud. If you reinstall your game, you will start over with the last cloud save.

Comment: Not necessarily true since CoC is an online game, it most likely just linked the CoC user ID to the Google Play account. However  this is speculation and yours is the best answer to remain on the safe side of things.

Comment: thank you people. And Fabian, i you didnt got what i meant to say